# Generate a Popup window in Android Map App using Mapbox SDK

Tags: android, dictionary, mapbox

I am developing a map app in Android using Mapbox Android SDK. I want to creat a popup on map when tap on map. Please note that not on any icon or marker. The popup should appear at the pin point of tapping position. The position information in longitude and latitude can be get from the following code.

```
@Override
            public void onTapMap(MapView pMapView, ILatLng pPosition) {
                String coords = String.format("Zoom = %f, Lat = %f, Lon = %f", pMapView.getZoomLevel(), pPosition.getLatitude(), pPosition.getLongitude());
                String utfGrid = MapboxUtils.getUTFGridString(pPosition, Float.valueOf(pMapView.getZoomLevel()).intValue());
                Log.i("TapForUTFGridTestFrag", String.format("coords = '%s', UTFGrid = '%s'", coords, utfGrid));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), coords + " == " + utfGrid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

I am actually want to get the following design. the red popup window's lower pin will be positined at the tapping position.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 2):

using the Mapbox Android SDK 4.0.0 beta version, you can get the latlng location where the user clicked by using a listener:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            mapboxMap.setOnMapClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {

                    mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .icon(/* make a marker bubble icon */)
                            .position(point));

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

What I mean by the `make a bubble icon` comment is to create a bitmap drawable that looks like the icons here:

[image]

Hope this helps and feel free to ask any questions

Comment: Thanks, but actually I want to create a popup menu window. In the web version of Google Maps if you right click then a context menu will appear with few menus like "Whats here", "Distance from here", or Distance to here". I can get the longitude latitude from the code I provided in the question. What I need is to create popup menu window that contain few menus and that will appear at the long-lat position with a lower pin.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to add a custom marker at that location which can be demonstrated via the following guide:

Drawing a marker
https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/marker/

Hint: use the following method:

```
mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(48.13863, 11.57603))
            .title("Hello World!")
            .snippet("Welcome to my marker."));
```

Since you do not wish to have a marker symbol there, I would suggest that you use the creating a custom marker guide and just pass a totally transparent marker:

https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/custom-marker-icon/

Comment: Thanks, but actually I want to create a popup menu window. In the web version of Google Maps if you right click then a context menu will appear with few menus like "Whats here", "Distance from here", or Distance to here". I can get the longitude latitude from the code I provided in the question. What I need is to create popup menu window that contain few menus and that will appear at the long-lat position with a lower pin.